# Find a list of modules that 'altered' a specific form in Drupal

Tags: drupal, module, form-api

Is there a trick, addon or patch that allows me to find out what modules [altered](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) a specfic form?

A list of all hook_form_alters is not too hard to achieve. But I want to list only those that actually changed my form.

Modules can alter a form trough a generic `modulename_form_alter()` and `modulename_form_FORMID_alter()` it would be nice if both are taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drupal_prepare_form function calls all hook_form_alter functions.  In this function, there is no storage for any modules that implement hook_form_alter.  However, there is a container ($data) there that pulls all the alter functions then is applied with drupal_alter.  Getting this data would require modifying this file (ref: line 543 in /includes/form.inc in Drupal 6.19).

Comment: I poked around there already. But $data is quite "fluid", so comparing one $data to another $data, in order to find if a form was "altered" does not work. It will (somehow) always return TRUE: somehow $data is changed on each iteration here.